# How to set the flutter application window alway keep on desktop

Tags: flutter, winapi

【Win10,Win11】I am a flutter developer and I need to pin the flutter application window to the windows desktop. It looks like it's embedded in the desktop, but it's not. It will block the Windows+D shortcut key, or display the desktop and other user operations. However, it will always be displayed on the desktop until the user closes it.

It will look like one of the app windows in the picture below. How should I implement this or is there any other third-party library that can help me.

[image: App windows]

I tried to modify the win32_window.cpp file in the windows/runner directory in the flutter project, but it had no effect.

Comment: The OS does not provide this functionality.

Comment: There should be a way to solve it. After all, many applications have already done this.